# What is the datatype of a Java varargs (...) parameter?

Tags: java

I am trying to add information from main()
to a items class where i am storing the information in a hashset

i have 3 classes

1. project - main()
2. libaray -  addBandMembers function
3. Item - addband(String... member)

i am adding CD information. first, i add band, # of songs, title - which works good

then in another function i am trying to add the band members. I want to keep these separate.
Where i am having problems is assign the band members..

I understand that how Varargs works just not sure how to assign that to a string..

I will only show bits of code to keep this post simple and short..

this is what i have:

Main()

```
item = library.addMusicCD("Don't Let Go", "Jerry Garcia Band", 15, "acid rock", "jam bands");
if (item != null) {
library.addBandMembers(item, "Jerry Garcia", "Keith Godcheaux");
library.printItem(out, item);
}
```

Then, here the first function thats called..

```
public void addBandMembers(Item musicCD, String... members)
{

   //musicCD.addband(members);   // both cant find addband function..
    //Item.addband(members);

}
```

Then in another class i am trying to add the information..

```
 private String members;  


public void addband(String... member)
{
    this.members = member;     // error

}
```

if i make the private String members; an array
then this function below errors.. incompatible type..

```
 public String getMembers()
{
 return members;   
}
```

How can i do this?

oh ya, here is my set..

```
public class Library
{
private Set<CD> theCDs = new HashSet<CD>();
private Set<DVD> theDVDs = new HashSet<DVD>();
private Set<Book> theBooks = new HashSet<Book>();
```

if you need to see more code let me know..
Thank you so much..

Answer (score 2):

A [varargs argument](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) resolves to an [array](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

So, change

```
private String members;
```

to

```
private String[] members;
```

Comment: how do i return the public String getMembers()
 function as an array?

Comment: Replace `public String getMembers()` by `public String[] getMembers()`. Please click the provided link behind "array" to learn more about arrays. If you want to go a step further, head to Collections API: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/index.html A `List<String>` is easier/better/nicer to handle than `String[]`.

Comment: using your suggestion regarding collections..
would i do something like this private List<String> members;
instead of private string[] members?

Comment: I honestly think it's better to take a step back and (re)do the "Trails Covering the Basics" here: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/

Comment: im still having a problem calling the public void addband(String... member) function from public void addBandMembers(Item musicCD, String... members)

Comment: Honestly and once again, all with all it look like that you have a lack of fundamental understanding how to write code in Java and that's not only varargs. I strongly recommend to check the link about "Trails Covering the Basics" I suggested before. It should get you through all the trivial stuff you need to know. I am also a bit surprised that you get that far as shown in the code you posted in your question. With the proven knowledge in the posted code, you should already be able to fix those minor issues yourself. Was the posted code copypasted from someone else or so?

Comment: i am coming from c++ i took data structures last course and i am trying to apply what i know to java.

Comment: OK, to the point, just replace `String members` by `String[] members` anywhere. `members` is now a `String` **array** and not a `String` anymore. That's it. You can alternatively also go for `List<String>` instead of `String[]`.

Comment: thank you so much.. i will review all of the java stuff also..
in the public void addBandMembers(Item musicCD, String... members)
cant i just pass members to addband?
like musicCD.addband(members); ????

Answer (score 1):

Change your getter to return a String array instead of a String.

Answer (score 1):

String... member gives you an array, so what you are looking at is a member that is of type String[].

I think once you get that, you kind of get over the hump of the issue.